# iphone app streaming video bandwidth check

Tags: iphone, bandwidth

I have an iphone app, which plays live streaming videos.
I want to check the bandwidth of the users connection, depending on which i will assign low, medium or high streaming to

**Any idea on how to check the users bandwidth / internet connection speed?**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would probably be to have your app stream a known file from your server on startup. This should tell you how fast their data rate is at the moment.

You could do this streaming in a background thread while the app is running so the user wouldn't have to wait for the test to complete.

The easiest way to do this would just be use the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to get the file asynchronously and use the [connection:didRecieveData:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get a measure of the data rate.

Sam